# How can I format 2 decimal places in monetary amount?

Tags: java, decimal, currency, decimalformat

i was assigned a question to design a java program to calculate the price of a pizza, this is what I tried:

```
        String diameter;
        diameter = this.txtInput.getText();
        
        // variable declaration and intialize for "labourCost" and "storeCost"
        double labourCost, storeCost;
        labourCost = 1;
        storeCost = 1.5;       
        
        // convert the value inputted from a string to double
        double dblDiameter= Double.parseDouble(diameter);
        
        // variable declarationa and intialize the value for the variable "cost"
        double cost = (labourCost + storeCost + (0.5 * dblDiameter));
        
        // print the output
        this.lblOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + cost);
```

The output I got is $7.5, my question is how can I format it so it will display $7.50? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

And then:

```
this.lblOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + decimalFormat.format(cost));
```

Or you can use `String.format`:

```
this.lblOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + String.format("%.2f", cost));
```

Comment: `DecimalFormat("#.##")` won't work in this case as `decimalFormat.format(cost)` will still print `7.5`. You need to use `new DecimalFormat("#.00")`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [`BigDecimal#setScale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,java.math.RoundingMode)) as shown below:

```
this.lblOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + BigDecimal.valueOf(cost).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

Alternatively, you can use [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) as shown below:

```
this.lblOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + String.format("%.2f", cost));
```

Another option is by using [`DecimalFormat#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double)) as shown below:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
this.lblOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + formatter.format(cost));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at different ways to use currency in java, I have the same problem. So it loosk like that the MonetaryAmount object does not handle formatting, and you have to use formatting objects.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @kk.Since you reviewed this post and you think it should be a comment, why is it still here?